# Google Group API list members

Tags: list, member, google-admin-sdk, google-groups-api

I tried to get list of my google group from this page: [reference/members/list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list)
And used the group ID/Name/Email as groupKey value, but get only this response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Resource Not Found: groupKey"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Resource Not Found: groupKey"
 }
}
```

I wonder am I specified wrong key or what is wrong? I haven't used google apis before, just want to try.

I haven't tried that api in my code, just wanted to try in "sandbox" before.

Comment: I have this error too, when using Google Apps Script:


`page = AdminDirectory.Members.list({
        groupKey: thisGroupEmail,
        pageToken: pageToken
});`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error 404 which means no resources available or cannot find the resources for the given groupKey.

- Create a group in G suite
- Add at least one user. No need to do that if you already created. But make sure that you have created the group.
- Come back to Google APIs Explorer
- Provide group's email ID as value.
- Complete your authentication & authorization using G suite credentials. You may be logged in using your personal email ID. Make sure you have completed authorization using G suite account.
- you will get the list of members from the group

Before tried to list all the members from the group (list members), just try to get one member (get members). It will help you in some cases.